# Why main can not be a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, program-entry-point, language-lawyer, constexpr

When you attempt to use constexpr with `main` like this:

```
constexpr int main()
```

gcc and clang complain:

> error: cannot declare '::main' to be inline
>
> error: 'main' is not allowed to be declared constexpr

Let's see what requirements for constexpr function are:

A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:

- it must not be virtual
- its return type must be LiteralType
- each of its parameters must be literal type

What is LiteralType?

A literal type is any of the following

- void(since c++14)
- scalar type
- reference type
- an array of literal type

What must the function body include?

- null statements
- static_assert declarations
- typedef declarations and alias declarations that do not define classes or enumerations
- using declarations
- using directives
- exactly one return statement that contains only literal values, constexpr variables and functions.

The following examples:

```
constexpr int main() { ; }

constexpr int main() { return 42; }

constexpr int main() {
// main defaults to return 0 
}
```

seems to fit all these requirements. Also with that, `main` is special function that runs at start of program before everything else. You can run constexpr functions from main, and in order for something marked constexpr to be constexpr, it must be run in a constexpr context.

So why is `main` not allowed to be a constexpr?

Comment: It seems to me like there is an obsession with some people to use new language features **everywhere**, regardless of if it makes sense.

Comment: Will this be the feature required to get rid of `fork` and `exec` to just execute `/bin/false`?

Comment: Also argc and argv can never be known at compile-time.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: you could actually optimize away any calling of `/bin/false`!

Comment: I am not sure I get the close votes as opinion based, all of the answers are pretty factual.

Comment: the problem isn't with the definition of constexpr, it is with the definition of main

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, this is not allowed the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in section `3.6.1` *Main function* paragraph *3* says:

> [...]A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is ill-formed.[...]

`main` has to be a run-time function and as [Lightness says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539744/why-main-can-not-be-a-constexpr#comment32527813_21539787) it makes no sense since you can't optimize `main` away.

Comment: But my question is why?

Comment: @ToryWebster Because it makes absolutely no sense to declare `main` as constexpr.

Comment: I ask same question I ask user3175411: "But what about C++14 relaxed constexpr restrictions? Will constexpr main be valid in future if compiler inserts codes that conform to these relaxed restrictions?"

Comment: @ToryWebster I doubt it. There is _no_ reason to do it, so I don't see why the standards committee would ratify such a rule. `main` never needs to be called in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: @ToryWebster if main was a no-op then you might as well not create an executable at all

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Oh? `static int foo = computationThatTakesThreeWeeks(); int main() {}`

Answer (score 27):

The standard gives the precise signature for `main`, so the compiler is allowed to reject other signatures. Even more specifically, it prescribes that `main` cannot be `constexpr`, `static`, or some other things.

If you're wondering *why*, the compiler is allowed to insert code at the beginning of `main` (to do stuff like initialize global variables, etc.) which could make it non-`constexpr` (which is why e.g. a program is not allowed to call main explicitly).

Comment: But what about C++14 relaxed constexpr restrictions? Will constexpr main be valid in future if compiler inserts codes that conform to these relaxed restrictions?

Comment: @ToryWebster I expect not. That would make for non-portable code and I think the standard will not stop explicitly prohibiting `constexpr` `main`.

Comment: Typically, that stuff does not happen in `main`, but in an implementation define entry-point that invokes `main`. So this isn't quite right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess we can only guess at the rationale (unless someone has a quote explaining it). My guess was that they didn't want to prohibit the compiler from doing it in `main` itself.

Comment: @user3175411: That's possible. Really it just makes no sense to allow it. You can't optimise `main` away at compile-time.

Comment: The reason goes one step further still. There is in fact no requirement for a function main to exist in the final binary. It is merely a unique name that the compiler can treat specially, just like constructors etc. That is one of the reasons that you are never allowed to call main from within your code (and some platforms actually take advantage of that).

Comment: @John5342 hmm, that's interesting. Could you give a standard reference for that?

Comment: @user3175411 look up one of the questions on the allowed signatures for main. There are some standardese quotes on that matter.

Comment: @TimSeguine: The standard says no such thing about `main` specifically, but the _as-if_ rule covers it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was referring to the fact that a non-hosted implementation isn't required to have `main`. But I realize now that John5342 probably _did_ mean the as-if rule

Comment: @TimSeguine: Well a `main` that does not exist cannot be `constexpr`, _or_ not-`constexpr` ;)

Comment: I was indeed referring to the as if rule combined with not being allowed to call main. I remember mailing list post from somebody involved in adding that loophole in the initial standard (and the reasoning). Will post back if i find it.

Comment: @John5342 I would appreciate the link if you find it, might even be worth adding an answer.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't make any sense to declare main as `constexpr` for two reasons: 1) It is a run-time function. 2) it may not be called from other functions or recursively.

Comment: +1 (when I get fresh votes tomorrow): this is what I was going to say, also.

Comment: +1 I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see anything factually wrong with this answer.

Comment: Maybe because of circular reasoning: what does "run-time" mean? "Not `constexpr`" seems a most reasonable definition.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the reason is that it makes no sense to declare `main()` as a `constexpr` and the standards committee want the C++ programming language to make sense.

The function `main()` is a special function that deals with program entry-point initialization - it is not sensible to use it to calculate compile-time values.